# Should you use only hover or both hover & focus on links?

Tags: html, css, hover, focus, anchor

I have usually used both which seemed pretty obvious, so once you clicked something and hovered away, the button remains focused(focus and hover having same styles) until lets say another page appears, but I noticed with some iOS devices that when you press the button but press back to return previous page the focus is still on the button you clicked before.

I can't quite decide, just looking for a second opinion?

Comment: Post the code which you tried.

Comment: This site isn't really for opinion-based answers, but I'd say only hover would be pretty useless on touch screen ;)

Comment: If this is what the question aims for, have a look at [ux.stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com). There are several questions on hover and focus states, e.g. [if they should be distinct](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/73403/51566). I could bet that every answer there would say that from a ux point of view (in particular related to *accessibility*) the focus state is useful.